# Finding schedule overlaps with Ruby & Runt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails to build a simple application to keep track of a shop's opening and closing times and its appointments, and I'm having some trouble validating the appointments against closings in the shop's schedule.

I've been using [Runt](http://runt.rubyforge.org/) to compose the schedule.  For example, if the shop is open Monday morning from 9am-12pm closed for an hour for lunch and then open in the afternoon until 5pm, it would look like:

```
require 'runt'
include Runt

monday = DIWeek.new(Mon)
morning = REDay.new(9,00,12,00)
afternoon = REDAy.new(13,00,17,00)

expr = monday & morning & afternoon
```

For a given appointment (also a Runt Temporal Expression), how can I make sure that the appointment **does** overlap with the opening times and **does not** overlap the lunch hour (or other times before or after the opening times)?

I gather that Runt has an overlaps? method, but if I do something like:

```
expr.overlaps?(DIWeek.new(Mon) & REDay.new(10,00,11,00)) # the appointment is from 10-11am on Monday and should overlap the morning opening time
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `overlaps?' for #<Runt::Intersect:0x10483cc>
```

Can anyone please advises me on how to correct this error or else another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlaps? method is defined only on Runt::Collection and Runt::DateRange. Perhaps you can create a DateRange object from your expr and then run overlap? on it.